# Does graphene-django dynamically create an API documentation?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm considering using GraphQL with a Django backend service but I couldn't find much information regarding the API documentation. I need some solution to dynamically generate the documentation, perhaps like npm's [graphql-docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-docs) with a result similar to [GitHub's API docs](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

Is it feasible to accomplish with [graphene-django](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/)? If not, what's a good alternative for a python environment?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's very easy to do by using [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql), which is embedded in to Graphene.

The instructions on how to integrate this with Graphene are [here in the graphene-python documentation](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#creating-graphql-and-graphiql-views). --- basically you need to add the parameter `graphiql=True` when setting up the API route in your `urls.py` file.

After it is set up, if go to your API endpoint in your browser, you'll see a nice interface for sending API calls, getting API responses, and reading documentation for both queries and mutations.  The documentation is initially hidden on the right until you click on the "< Docs" link.